# add each row label (based on condition) panadas groupby result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to apply simple functions to groups in pandas. I have this result of group dataframe (grouped on user_id) like this:

```
user_id           cancelled_at  
10                NaN   
10                2021-02-26  
10                NaN   
10                NaN   
10                2021-06-01   
10                NaN
```

I want to add label to each row based on condition at 'cancelled_at' column
like this:

```
user_id    cancelled_at   result 
10    NaN                 cancel
10    2021-02-26          cancel
10    NaN                 renew
10    NaN                 cancel
10    2021-06-01          cancel
10    NaN                 renew
```

the non-null 'cancelled_at' ROW value and its previous row has result cancel otherwise result is renew

Answer (score 0):

If need set `1` if previous values of `cancelled_at` are not missing per groups use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with helper column for compare by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df['Result'] = (df.assign(new = df.cancelled_at.notna())
                  .groupby('user_id')['new']
                  .shift(fill_value=False)
                  .astype(int))
print (df)
   user_id  start_date    end_date cancelled_at  Result
0       10  2020-12-27  2021-01-26          NaN       0
1       10  2021-01-27  2021-02-26   2021-02-26       0
2       10  2021-02-28  2021-03-30          NaN       1
3       10  2021-03-31  2021-04-30          NaN       0
4       10  2021-05-02  2021-06-01   2021-06-01       0
5       10  2021-06-02  2021-07-02          NaN       1
```

Performance should be slowier, but is possible use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    return x.notna().shift(fill_value=False).astype(int)

df['Result'] = df.groupby('user_id')['cancelled_at'].transform(f)
print (df)

   user_id cancelled_at  Result
0       10          NaN       0
1       10   2021-02-26       0
2       10          NaN       1
3       10          NaN       0
4       10   2021-06-01       0
5       10          NaN       1
```

Comment: hey @jezrael ,Can it be done by applying custom function to each groupby result?   
like df = df.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: my_function(x,))

Comment: @AsadKhalil - Answer was edited.

Comment: @jazrael your code is not working

Comment: @AsadKhalil - Can you be more specific?